# Restructure data.frame By Date Values in R

Tags: r, date, data-frame

I have a data.frame in R shown below..

[image]

This data.frame summarizes counts by week for every year in a time series dataset.

I am now trying to rearrange this matrix such that the years (2001-2020) will be the columns, the weeks (1-52) will be the rows, and the sumweek column is the data that I would like to use to fill in the matrix.

Is there an easy solution for this?

Comment: This is a general R question and not GIS-related enough to be here. Try stackoverflow.com for anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, use the `pivot_wider()` function from tidyr. I assume you want to retain the state column too; if you don't want the state, remove that from the id_cols argument.

```
library(tidyr)

mydata = data.frame("weeks" = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                    "year" = rep(c(2001:2004), 2),
                    "state" = rep("Florida", 8),
                    "sumWeek" = c(10,100,204,4920,203,3,401,94))

myData_wide = pivot_wider(mydata, 
                          id_cols = c("weeks", "state"),
                          names_from = year, 
                          values_from = sumWeek)
myData_wide
```

Comment: Indeed, this is exact solution I was looking for. Thank you very much